# Matching file contents with patterns/regex (repost after edit)

Tags: regex, file-comparison

As part of a repeatable testing approach I'm looking to run a process and then compare its log file with an expected result.  Here is a simplified example of the log file produced:

```
2020-09-01_01:00:00.000 INFO  : Incoming record count 123

2020-09-01_01:00:00.010 INFO  : Valid record count 120
```

I cannot use a static file to compare against using "diff" as the time stamps would change on each run (as would some other parts of the log contents).  I'm thinking of using a file of regex's and using grep in a loop.  A comparison file might look like:

```
^....-..-.._..:..:..\.... INFO  : Incoming record count [0-9]+$

^....-..-.._..:..:..\.... INFO  : Valid record count [0-9]+$
```

I would then use a loop to take a line at a time from the log file and the pattern file and compare the two using grep.  Here is some pseudo-code for this:

```
while not eof

   read next line from log file

   read next line from pattern file

   grep pattern-line log-line

   if not matched then error and break loop

end
```

While functional this seems inefficient and inelegant so I'm looking for alternatives, or for comments that this actually a valid approach.

Comment: You could implode all regexes into one separated by `|`.

Also, you regexes look to relaxed. It should be more like `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} INFO  : (Incoming|Valid) record count \d+$`.

Comment: I simplified the regex's just for the example.

I can't implode them to a single one because my log files have a number of lines - 2 in the example above - and the need to be those exact messages in that exact order.